# How can I create a 3D radial "beams" with shader nodes?

Tags: shader-nodes

I would like to create a proceedural texture in which "beams" eminate from the center of an object - think of light beams coming out of a point light source. The following node set-up does this perfectly in 2D:
[image][image]

However if applied to a sphere you see that the beams are only eminating from the center on the X/Y plane, not the Z axis.

If the "beams" eminated from the center they would appear as spots on the surface of a sphere like in my example.

Please note: I realise I could use voranoi if spots on the surface are my end goal, but I'm intending to use this texture to control the density parameter of a volume shader, so the solution needs to create "beams" radiating from the center of the object outwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - it's a bit hackish, but it might work for you. Start by breaking a radial gradient into "slices" using a ColorRamp set to *constant*. Use as many "white bits" as you need.

[image: Beam1]

Take the result and multiply a *Normalized* wave texture (on the Z-axis) over it to chop up the beams vertically. The Normalize (Vector math) node makes the beam "cones" point on an angle.

[image: Beam2]

Lastly, multiply a *spherical* gradient over the whole thing to give falloff to the edges.

[image: Beam3]

Alternatively, you could use a Volume Scatter node (instead of an emission), and place a point light right at the center:

[image: Beam4]

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do it by manipulating texture coordinates, but I've not come up with anything better than this approach which does indeed create the effect I'm after.